# Get names of tabs in Excel workbook and use just one

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I've got an Excel workbook, and needed to read data from the third (and final) worksheet in that workbook. I used old code that scanned through all worksheets, but modified it to jump to the third worksheet:

```
foreach (var worksheet in Workbook.Worksheets(excelInput).skip(2))
```

This took me to the third worksheet, my code would execute, and everything was fine.

Now, the client is sending either a three-tabbed Workbook with the sheet I need elsewhere (either 1st or 2nd tab), or they're sending a four-tabbed Workbook, and the sheet I need could be anywhere.

Is there a way to choose the one-and-only sheet that I need by either finding the name of the tab, or the text in cell A1, and using that worksheet and that worksheet only?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know “where” the worksheet is located in the workbook, you can loop through each sheet and check either the sheet name, or as you say “text in cellA1”.

Checking the text in cell A1… I am not sure how you would know if the sheet was the proper one by looking at the first cell. What if all sheets have a value in the first cell? And what would that cell contain? Would the cell contain text that says “this is the correct sheet”? So I am assuming that this workbook only has one sheet with data, and the other sheets are empty.

Looping through the sheets in the workbook is relatively easy, however if you do not know what the name of the sheet is, then it may be difficult to identify the proper sheet. Using my assumption (above) of only one sheet with data, then you can check each sheet to see how many rows of data each sheet has. Then the one with more than 1 row of data is the sheet you are looking for. If the other sheets have data also, then this won’t work and you are going to have to identify the target sheet some other way.

If you DO KNOW the name of the worksheet, then you are good to go. In your case you stated that the worksheet was “Sheet3” but may not be in the 3rd index of the worksheets in the workbook. In this case you can reference the sheet by name as you asked with:

```
Worksheet target = workbook.Sheets[“Sheet3”];
```

If `target` returns null, then the worksheet named “Sheet3” does not exist. If target is not null, then you have found the worksheet and it can be referenced by the `target` Worksheet variable.

From what you described, if the sheet is always named ”Sheet3” then simply use:

```
if (SheetExist(workbook, "Sheet3"))
{
  Worksheet myWS = workbook.Sheets["Sheet3"];
  if (myWS.Cells[1,1].Value != null)
    Console.WriteLine("\nCell[1,1] of sheet3: " + myWS.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString() + "\n");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("\nCell[1,1] of sheet3 is Null/has no value");
}
else
{
   //Console.WriteLine("Worksheet NOT found!");
   // sheet named "Sheet3" does not exist in the workbook
}
```

Below is a method that you can use to see if a "worksheet" with the supplied name “sheetName” exist in the given ”workbook.” If you need the index of the worksheet you could change this to return the index or -1 if it does not exist.

```
private static bool SheetExist(Excel.Workbook workbook, string sheetName)
{
  Worksheet target = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
  if (target != null)
  {
    //Console.WriteLine("Worksheet found!");
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    //Console.WriteLine("Worksheet NOT found!");
    return false;
  }
```

A method that loops through all the sheets and checks the number of rows with data using the “UsedRange” function. This also identifies the index of the worksheet in the workbook.

```
private static void LoopThruAllSheets(Workbook workbook)
{
  Sheets allWorkSheets = workbook.Worksheets;
  foreach (Worksheet curWS in allWorkSheets)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Worksheet : at index " + curWS.Index + " name: " + curWS.Name.ToString() + " UsedRange.Rows.Count: " + curWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count.ToString());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps